# DotnetOpenAuth by asp.net occurred the error This message can only be sent over HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, oauth, https, dotnetopenauth

In using DotnetOpenAuth by asp.net on

```
var request = await Client.PrepareRequestUserAuthorizationAsync(scopes, cancellationToken:Response.ClientDisconnectedToken);
```

occurred the **error**:"`DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: This message can only be sent over HTTPS`".

Anywhere to setting?

Comment: Did you try this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265944/dotnetopenauth-throws-a-protocolexception

Comment: Apart from above link 

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dotnetopenid/5EYoEDAPLTc

Comment: I find the matter. <dotNetOpenAuth> <messaging relaxSslRequirements="true">

Comment: Did above link helped?

Answer (score 0):

sink is correct.

add the following to your app.config or web.config file

```
<dotNetOpenAuth>
<messaging relaxSslRequirements="true"/>
```